# How to add component programatically with Modifiers = public during design time in c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, code-generation, windows-forms-designer

I would like to add a component to my control programatically in design time, however i'd like for the control to have its Modifiers property set to public so it would generate a public memeber.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm currently getting an IDesignerHost instance in my VS extension like this:

```
IDesignerHost _host = (IDesignerHost)ApplicationObject.ActiveWindow.Object;
```

And im adding components like so:

```
IComponent c = _host.CreateComponent(_host.GetType("System.Data.DataColumn,System.Data"), "testdc");
```

My end goal is to generate/regenerate a component (based on a database resource) that would act as a wrapper for a certain consumer of the data. Also i'd like for the component to still be designer editable being able to make manual changes. I have my base code, but im bumping into issues such as the one presented above. I have considered generating the source code directly, but that would knock the designer out as an option for editing later.

Comment: Is the *component* a `DataColumn` or it's just an example?

Comment: There are multiple components of different types that i'm adding, one if them is DataColumn